# Check if Tomcat and MySQL are already installed on machine

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat

How can I check using Java if Tomcat and MySQL are already installed on machine? If it is installed I have to disable those options in my installer.

Comment: check the environment variables e.g CATALINA_HOME

Answer (score 2):

If Tomcat is installed as a service on Windows, you can check the registry:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat\[version]\InstallPath`.

To read the registry from Java, you would need to use something like [JNA](http://jna.java.net/), the methods 
`Advapi32Util.registryGetKeys()` and `Advapi32Util.registryGetStringValue()` can help.