# How can I make sure tomcat is installed in windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, tomcat

I am writing a batch script to install tomcat in windows. As part of this, I want to check if the tomcat is already installed in the server (either as a service or by environmental variable).

Please let me know the best way to achieve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if Tomcat and MySQL are already installed on machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7550535/check-if-tomcat-and-mysql-are-already-installed-on-machine)

Comment: The given link says, only if tomcat is installed as service on windows.

Comment: I want to know however tomcat is running.
1. we can start as service
2. we can deploy tomcat and we can run catalina.bat ot startup.bat to start  tomcat
3. some people won't even setup CATALINA_HOME environment variable, they directly goto tpmcat/bin folder and they will start tomcat.

So, I want to identify if tomcat is running on the system irrespective of the way it is configured/started.

if it is linux, we can simply check the processes running.
eg: ps -ef|grep tomcat

please guide me.

Comment: How about `jps` command?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I will take a look on jps and jcmd

Answer (score 0):

To verify that Tomcat is installed  on your windows, double click on `tomcat-directory/bin/startup.bat`. Open a browser,

If you didn't change the port to `80`,then enter `http://localhost:8080/`